# What does TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__' mean?

Tags: python-2.7, file, syntax-error

I have this code:

```
     My_Directory = r"/Users/schuylerraeschroerborges/Desktop/Mars_Project/mcam_image_and_label/0984MR0043380090502893E01_DRCL"     # Get data from directory
     My_Extension = ".LBL"

     WorkingDirectory = "/Users/schuylerraeschroerborges/Desktop/Mars_Project/"  # Work in same directory

     f = open('mcam_image_and_label/0984MR0043380090502893E01_DRCL.LBL','r')    # Open label file
     lines = f.readlines() #index lines
     g = open('Expanded_data.csv','w+')   # Write in excel spreadsheet
     lines = g.readlines()


     ID_line = f[21]
     ID = re.split('"',f[21])[2]
     LO_line = f[134]
     LO = re.split('(',f[134])[2]
     DI_line = f[442]
     DI = re.split('=',f[442])[2]
     AZ_line = f[445]
     AZ = re.split('=',f[445])[2]
     VE_line = f[446]
     VE = re.split('=',f[446])[2]
     newline = ID + '\t' + LO + '\t' + DI + '\t' + AZ + '\t' + VE + '\n'
     g.writelines(newline)
```

I keep gettting this error, TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '_getitem__', after I run the code in Python 2.7. What does this error mean? Do I need to change the name of a file or something?

Comment: You stored the lines in `lines`, not `f`; `f` is the file object. (And you’ll probably not want to call `readlines()` on the output file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to index object `f` which is a `file` like object returned by `open()` function.

Internally, indexing is implemented via `__getitem__` special method which the `file` object doesn't implement, this is the reason you are seeing that error message.

The error is on the line where you are trying to assign `ID_lines = f[21]`, perhaps you want to assign `lines[21]` instead.

Comment: I get this error when I change "f[21]" to "lines[21]": IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Mark: That's probably because you're overwriting the `lines` you read from `f` with an empty list of lines read from `g` (which is truncated when you open it with mode `"w+"`).